# Azure VMs fails as public ip is allocated to other resource

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, infrastructure-as-code

I am using a powershell script to create multiple Vms based on an image. The first Vm is ok but when attempting the second Vm I get an error saying that :

```
 | Resource /subscriptions/....../networkInterfaces/xxxxx/ipConfigurations/xxxxx is referencing public IP address
 | /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSPublicIpAddress that is already allocated to
 | resource /subscriptions/......./networkInterfaces/xxxxx/ipConfigurations/xxxxx.
```

Here is the script I am using:

```
param(
        [string] $WeekNo="NoWeek",
        [int] $VmCount=0
        )
        
#$cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter a username and password for the virtual machine."

## VM Account
# Credentials for Local Admin account you created in the sysprepped (generalized) vhd image
$VMLocalAdminUser = "xxxxx"
$VMLocalAdminSecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxxxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
$image = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/xxxxxxxxx"
## Azure Account
$LocationName = "SwedenCentral"
$ResourceGroupName = "xxxx_" + $WeekNo

if( -Not( Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $LocationName -ErrorAction Ignore)) {

New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $LocationName
Write-Host "ResourceGroup" $ResourceGroupName "created"

$VMSize = "Standard_B2ms"

## Networking
$NetworkName = "xxxxxx_" + $WeekNo + "_net" # "MyNet"


$SubnetName = "MySubnet"
$SubnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/24"
$VnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/16"

$SingleSubnet = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $SubnetName -AddressPrefix $SubnetAddressPrefix
$Vnet = New-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $NetworkName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $LocationName -AddressPrefix $VnetAddressPrefix -Subnet $SingleSubnet
}


$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($VMLocalAdminUser, $VMLocalAdminSecurePassword);
$VMName = "xxxx" + $WeekNo

##New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $LocationName -VM $VirtualMachine -Verbose -Image $image
for($i=1; $i -le $VmCount; $i++){
$VMBaseName = "iCPSEDU" + $WeekNo + $i

$StorageAccount = "xxxxx" + $WeekNo + $i
$PublicIPAddressName = $VMBaseName  + "PIP$(Get-Random)"
$NICName = $VMBaseName + "NIC"
$DNSNameLabel = "xxxx" + $WeekNo + $i + "dns" # mydnsname.westus.cloudapp.azure.com

$PIP = New-AzPublicIpAddress -Name $PublicIPAddressName -DomainNameLabel $DNSNameLabel -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $LocationName -AllocationMethod Dynamic
$NIC = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name $NICName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $LocationName -SubnetId $Vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $PIP.Id


Write-Host "Creating VM " $VMBaseName

New-AzVm `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    -Name $VMBaseName `
    -ImageName $image `
    -Location $LocationName `
    -VirtualNetworkName $Vnet `
    -SubnetName $SubnetName `
    -SecurityGroupName "myImageNSG" `
    -PublicIpAddressName $PIP -Credential $Credential -Size $VMSize -PublicIpSku Standard


Write-Host "VM " $VMBaseName " Created"

Stop-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName $VMBaseName -Force -NoWait

Write-Host "VM " $VMBaseName " Stopped"

    }

Write-Host "Done."`
```

To me it seems that the variable used for the PIP is not "flushed" properly between the executions but I have no idea on how to do this?

Or is there something else causing the error?

I have tried adding some delays but without effect.

Comment: I have now looked further into the command New-AzVm which appearently creates the resource if not available. This will be useful in this case but I am still curiuos about why the creation above fails.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a public IP address and specify a DNS name
2. Create a NSG
3. Create a NIC and associate with created pub IP address and NSG
4. Create a virtual machine configuration and assign the NIC
5. Create the VM with the config

https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-samples/blob/master/virtual-machine/create-vm-detailed/create-windows-vm-detailed.ps1

rough summary of important steps:

```
$pip = New-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location `
  -Name "mypublicdns$(Get-Random)" -AllocationMethod Static -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 4

$nsg = New-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location `
  -Name myNetworkSecurityGroup -SecurityRules $nsgRuleRDP

$nic = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name myNic -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location `
  -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id

$vmConfig = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize Standard_D1 | `
Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -Windows -ComputerName $vmName -Credential $cred | `
Set-AzVMSourceImage -PublisherName MicrosoftWindowsServer -Offer WindowsServer -Skus 2016-Datacenter -Version latest | `
Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -Id $nic.Id

New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location -VM $vmConfig
```

MS is providing well tested powershell code for various tasks:

I prefer the github samples https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-samples over the steps in learn and doc.microsoft.com

also have a deeper look at the Azure CLI examples and template based deployments. It seems to me that MS is abandoning PS a bit.